# Wha HTTP status codes should be checked within my app

Tags: java, android, http, http-status-codes

i am just wondering about the HTTP status codes that should be checked against if something fails and i am returned within something other than the standard 202, there are alot of status codes but i am wondering what ones should be checked for the majority of the time,

i am using android but this is similar through the whole web, so it would nice if someone could tell which ones they test for and what messages they show to users.

and how would i find out the status code of a response in android?

Comment: Be sure to cover `418 I'm a teapot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what your servers is expected to send.

- 200, of course
- 201 if you create something (a post or sometimes a put)
- 202 if your server does not send anything (but it succeded) (most servers don't send that)
- 302 if your data can be moved (most httpclient do that for you)
- 304 if your data can be unmodified
- 401 if you are doing authentication
- 4xx for any other client side error
- 5xx for server side errors

Answer (score 2):

As a general-purpose thing, I tend to just check the 100's digit. 2=OK, 3=try again/look over here, 4=you made a mistake, 5 (or anything else)=they made a mistake. Usually, that's enough information for me to give reasonable feedback...

Although most HTTP libraries will handle the 3xx messages for me, if I ask them to, so at the application level, it's mostly a concern with 4xx versus 5xx messages.

Unless you have a specific reason to check for more specific codes, 4xx probably means that whatever request you sent was invalid for some reason — so I may want to ask the user for new input, or something like that; but 5xx generally means the server is "broken" and I need to tell the user that the "service is presently unavailable" or similar. I personally often funnel DNS and TCP connection errors into the same handler as 5xx errors… as a "client" side user of the server, it doesn't usually matter to me so much *why* the service is unavailable, only *whether* it is.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at handling these:  303, 400, 401, 404, 500, 503.